# Firebase/Flutter: User is not being deleted after function call

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

i have a problem because when i press button i have to delete `userData` from `FireStore`, next i want to delete `user` and go to a `loginPage`. Deleting `userData` works fine and i have no `documents` according to this `user`, the problem is deleting the `user` from `FirebaseAuth` i dunno why, but the function `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.delete())` is not being called after `.whenComplete()`, moreover my `Navigator` works fine and takes me to the `loginPage`.

So the main problem is that `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.delete())` call is just skipped dunno why.

> Here is my button with `onPressed function`:

```
CustomButton(
                            width: width * 0.9,
                            icon: Icons.delete,
                            text: 'Delete Account',
                            onPressed: () {
                              _authenticationService
                                  .deleteUserData(type).whenComplete(() => FirebaseAuth
                                      .instance.currentUser!
                                      .delete())
                                  .whenComplete(() => Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              LoginMenuPage())));
                            }),
```

> And here is my `deleteUserData()` function:

```
Future<void> deleteUserData(String type) async {
    final User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
    final CollectionReference _userCollectionRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    final CollectionReference _attendantCollectionRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('attendants');
    final CollectionReference _seniorCollectionRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('seniors');
    final CollectionReference _chatUserCollectionRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chatUsers');
    final CollectionReference _notificationsCollectionRef = FirebaseFirestore
        .instance
        .collection('seniors')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .collection('notifications');
    type == "Attendant"
        ? _userCollectionRef
            .doc(user.uid)
            .delete()
            .whenComplete(() => _attendantCollectionRef.doc(user.uid).delete())
            .whenComplete(() => _chatUserCollectionRef.doc(user.uid).delete())
        : _userCollectionRef
            .doc(user.uid)
            .delete()
            .whenComplete(() {
              _notificationsCollectionRef.doc('hunger').delete();
              _notificationsCollectionRef.doc('thirst').delete();
              _notificationsCollectionRef.doc('sleep').delete();
              _notificationsCollectionRef.doc('toilet').delete();
              _notificationsCollectionRef.doc('mood').delete();
            })
            .whenComplete(() => _seniorCollectionRef.doc(user.uid).delete())
            .whenComplete(() => _chatUserCollectionRef.doc(user.uid).delete());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh okay i found a solution, just had to make it asynchronous.
Here is the code from `onPressed call` which works well for me:

```
_authenticationService
                     .deleteUserData(type)
                                  .whenComplete(() async => await FirebaseAuth
                                      .instance.currentUser!
                                      .delete())
                                  .whenComplete(() => Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              LoginMenuPage())));
```